# What is the best diag tool for peugeot, citroen?

Tags: software

I know about lexia 3 interfaces and I know that diagbox and pp2000 are the actual genuine software from the manufacturer.

But there are knockoffs and I cant really get a genuine one. Is it ok to get a china made copy and if so are there differences with them, witch one is the best to get?

Also is there any car brand independent diagnostics software that does everything possible not just code readouts but manipulations in any possible way?

I hope I've been clear enough, Thanks.